# Une nuance entre « d'emblée » et « d'entrée »

Tags: expressions

> Elles se sont **d'emblée** entendues à merveille.
>
> Elles se sont **d'entrée** entendues à merveille.

Je crois que « d'emblée » sert à marquer la rapidité avec laquelle toutes deux se sont entendues, et on peut y substituer « immédiatement, aussi sec ».

« D'entrée », en revanche, signifie-t-il plutôt « dès le début (de leur relation) » ?

---

***UPDATE:***

I have come up with two separate sentences to highlight the difference between the two expressions. Am I on the right track here?

> 1 ○ : J'ai horreur qu'on m'interrompe quand je parle à quelqu'un, je te l'ai dit **d'entrée**.

{= **dès le début de la réunion**}

> 1 × : J'ai horreur qu'on m'interrompe quand je parle à quelqu'un, je te l'ai dit **d'emblée**.

{= **immédiatement**} Dans la phrase 1, l'emploi de « d'emblée » ne tient absolument pas debout.

---

> 2 ○ : Je lui ai dit **d'emblée** ce que je ressentais pour elle.

{= **immédiatement**}

> 2 × : Je lui ai dit **d'entrée** ce que je ressentais pour elle.

{= **dès le début de quoi ?**} Dans la phrase 2, l'emploi de « d'entrée » ne tient pas vraiment debout.

Answer (score 1):

#### Etymologie

Selon wiktionary :

- [d'emblée](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%E2%80%99embl%C3%A9e) signifie :

> Du premier effort ; du premier coup ; de plein saut.

- et [d'entrée](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%E2%80%99entr%C3%A9e) :

> Dès le début.
> (Comme tu l'as noté)

---

#### Sens

Dans **d’emblée**, on pointe **l'ordre** de l'action : c'est la première fois, pas la seconde.

Dans **d'entrée**, on insiste durant **quelle partie** de l'action se déroule l’événement : le début, pas la fin.

---

#### Concrètement

Ainsi pour tes deux exemples :

> Elles se sont d'emblée entendues à merveille.

Elles se sont entendues à merveille, **la première fois**, peut être qu'au contraire, la seconde fois, elles ne se sont pas autant appréciées.

> Elles se sont d'entrée entendues à merveille.

Elles se sont entendues à merveille, **dès le début**, mais, l'après midi passant, elles ont fini par ne plus se supporter.

---

**Le sens est très proche mais pas interchangeable !**

Comment: Pour ma part je comprends les deux phrases comme le fait que ça dure dans le temps. Je ne me vois pas utiliser *d'emblée* ou *d'entrée* pour ensuite le contredire. Surtout qu'en disant *dès*, pour moi ça sous-entend que ça dure. *J'ai aimé ce film dès la première scène !* ne me semble pas laisser place à la possibilité qu'il ne l'ait plus aimé à la quatrième scène.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Comme tu le notes, **d'entrée** a ce sens particulier, mais pas forcément **d'emblée**.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps & YohannV Si leur amitié n'a duré que pendant un court moment, personnellement j'emploierais « *au début* » et dirais : « ***Au début (de leur relation)**, elles s'entendaient à merveille, puis les choses se sont gâtées.* » Je me demande donc si on peut aussi utiliser « *d'emblée* » et « *d'entrée* » pour signifier « *au début* » ? Merci.

Comment: @LUNA personnellement je ferais comme toi, parce que *d'emblée* et *d'entrée* me semblent sous-entendre que ça dure par la suite, mais Yohann semble avoir fait des recherches donc peut-être que dans leur sens strict, étymologique, c'est possible.

Comment: Comme on l'avait noté en Q., _d'emblée_ peut aussi vouloir dire _immédiatement/tout de suite_, et vu la polysémie la confusion est possible. Tout comme elle devient aussi possible à l'oral avec un truc comme _je te l'ai dit d'entrée/d'entrer_, vu l'homophonie (_contra_ avec _d'entrée de jeu_). Par ailleurs, il y a le registre, et _d'entrée_ pourrait être surtout d'origine littéraire. Enfin ce sont des locutions adverbiales avec lesquelles on tente ici de faire une ellipse partielle d'un complément (moment de la rencontre), et de situer à la fois sans référent ; à mon avis imprécis et inusité.

Comment: @Faʁdɔʃɔtɔmatabaʁwɛt Sans avoir analysé autant que toi, je suis d'accord avec ton sentiment final ... Même si le fait de ressortir de vieilles expressions à l'oral donne un charme certain !